# How to limit the width of equations?

Tags: equations, minipage

I want to control the width of the equations so they don't exceed a predefined width. Firstly I used `minipage` environment and put the `eqnarray` within that. This does not produce the line breaks before and after the equations. I  manually use line break, then there would be extra space between text and equations. Is there any other way to set an specific width for an equation without affecting the line breaks? I specifically want to use `eqnarray` and not any other environments like `align` for typesetting equations.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \newenvironment{myenv}{ \begin{minipage}{5cm}\begin{eqnarray}
      }{\end{eqnarray}\end{minipage} }

\begin{document}


dummy text here
\begin{myenv}
  a &= s^3-s
  \\
  b &=s^2+s
\end{myenv}
dummy text here

\end{document}
```

[image]

with added line breaks:

```
\newenvironment{myenv}{\\ \begin{minipage}{5cm}\begin{eqnarray}
  }{\end{eqnarray}\end{minipage} \\}
```

[image]

Comment: It's best to avoid `\eqnarray`. See [`\eqnarray` vs `\align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln).

Comment: @ Wener: Thanks, I know about it. However due to some limitations of the class file I am using I can only use `eqnarray` and not `align`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what prevents you from using `align`? It really is a better tool for the job. I would sooner forego numbering entirely using `\[ maths \]`, or try to figure out how to do the equation numbering by hand, than use the equation spacing we see in your two examples.

Comment: @  Niel de Beaudrap: The reason is that, I am using `iopart` document class which is not compatible with `amsmath`. A related post can be seen here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95817/how-can-i-use-align-environment-in-conjuction-with-iopart-cls-class

Comment: have a look at `adjustwidth` from the `changepage` package- it should help with what you want...

Comment: If you _have_ to use `eqnarray` you should at least write `&=&` to get better spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \newenvironment{myenv}[1]
{\everydisplay{\setlength\displaywidth{#1}}\begin{eqnarray}}
{\end{eqnarray}\ignorespacesafterend}


\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

dummy text here X\dotfill X
\begin{myenv}{5cm}
  a &= s^3-s
  \\
  b &=s^2+s
\end{myenv}
dummy text here

dummy text here  X\dotfill X
\begin{myenv}{3cm}
  a &= s^3-s
  \\
  b &=s^2+s
\end{myenv}
dummy text here

dummy text here  X\dotfill X
\begin{myenv}{10cm}
  a &= s^3-s
  \\
  b &=s^2+s
\end{myenv}
dummy text here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David for your answer! This method seems to also affect the width of the paragraph coming before `\begin{myenv}{?}`. It would be clear if a longer dummy text is used before the new environment.

Comment: sorry, code fixed.

Comment: Thanks it works well. I am accepting it as answer since my problem might be too specific; I'm not sure however, why this does not work with `eqnarray` defined in `iopart`, when using `\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}` it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: just googled for a copy of iopart: change `\displaywidth` to `\linewidth` for their version