# Undefined control sequence with mhchem package

Tags: mhchem

I am using chemical reactions and formula in my document. However, I am getting a compiler error " undefined control sequence when using `\usepackage{mhchem}`. If remove `\usepackage{mhchem}`, my document compiles with errors due to using commands related to the `mhchem` package. For example, writing `\ce{H2O}`. This is the heading of the document.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\newcommand{\gguide}{{\it Preparing graphics for IOP journals}}
\begin{document}
Water vapor(\ce{H2O}
```

Any suggestions for me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! When trying to run your code, the log message reveals that `mhchem` loads `amsmath`, but [`iopart` does not seem to like `amsmath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95817/121799). It is really irritating that `iopart` has this "feature" and a bit surprising that `mhchem` loads `amsmath`. (And you might want to add an `\end{document}` to your code and replace `\it` by `\itshape`.) My conclusion is that you cannot have `iopart` and `mchem` at the same time.

Comment: I did not know that mhchem loads amsmath. There is an incompatibility between amsmath and iopart.cls. iopart is the class on the journal template. I will consult the journal service team about using a different class. Thank you! that was helpful.

Comment: Better yet, `\newcommand{\gguide}{\textit{Preparing graphics for IOP journals}}`

Comment: you are right. I commented this line and the codes compile well. Thanks for your help and the fast response!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments