# IOP Publication amsmath

Tags: amsmath

I'm using iopart.cls file and need to define arg max operator. So I defined the following:

\newcommand{\argmax}[1]{\underset{#1}{\operatorname{arg}\,\operatorname{max}}\;}

This needs amsmath but since IOP provides \underset, I think it should be fine but this operator gives me undefined control sequence.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Isn't iopart.cls compatible with `amsmath`?

Comment: Hello Bernard, thank you for the response. In here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95817/how-can-i-use-align-environment-in-conjuction-with-iopart-cls-class, someone suggested to put \expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax and
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax before \usepackage{amsmath}. I am not sure what it does but the error goes away. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: But maybe it is not incompatible with `amsopn.sty` which defines `\operatorname` and `\DeclareMathOperator`?

Answer (score 4):

If neither `amsopn.sty` is compatible with `iopart`, you can define the command directly

```
\newcommand{\argmax}{\mathop{\mathrm{arg\,max}}}
```

that should be called like

```
 \argmax_{x\in X}f(x)
```

and will print the subscript underneath “argmax” when in display style.

If loading `amsopn` is possible, then you can just do

```
\usepackage{amsopn}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
```

and call `\argmax` the same way.